# Delete Internet Explorer 8 History, Cookies, Cache and Passwords with C++

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, cookies, browser-cache

i need programmatically delete Internet Explorer 8 History, Cookies, Cache and Passwords

More than that i need to do it silently :-( without any popup window , so I can't use

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2
```

coz it's starting the progress window dialog.

I've tried to run this from CreateProcess function with startInfoParams

```
siStartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
siStartupInfo.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
```

but it doesn't helped , coz it seems like Inetcpl.cpl running asynchronious , and starting it's own thread that show the window.

Does anyone know the way to implement this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you writing a virus?

Comment: Not Exactly , a tool for IT guys. that allow in one click clear those things on 300+ workstations

Comment: Watching porn @work is a serious working codex violation :)

Comment: Except if you are working on VIVID ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry()`, `FindNextUrlCacheEntry()`, and `DeleteUrlCacheEntry()` to remove URLs and files from the Temporary Internet Files cache.

You can use `FindFirstUrlCacheEntryEx()` and  `FindNextUrlCacheEntryEx()` to enumerate Cache, History, and Cookies entries, but `DeleteUrlCacheEntry()` only works for Cache entries.  I don't know the correct way to delete entries from the History and Cookies.  You might be able to just get away with calling `DeleteFile()` on the filename reported in the `INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO` struct, if one is present.  Or maybe use `InternetSetCookie/Ex()` to overwrite the existing cookie data with a new timestamp that is expired.

I have no clue if it is possible to manipulate the Password list programmably.

Comment: DeleteFile() will not delete the entry in Index.dat. Additionally your application must run with Integrity Level Low if you want to access cookies of the internet zone which are stored in a separate folder and are not enumerated if your application runs with Medium or High Integrity level.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually delete all files located in TemporaryInternetFiles and similar directories. Just find out which ones you want deleted. To remove entire, non-empty directories, either use a combination of `FindNextFile` / `DeleteFile` / `DeleteDirectory`, or use `SHFileOperation`. There's working code on [codeguru](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=239271).

Comment: That deletes the physical files only.  The cache also maintains a database that refers to those files.  WinInet has its own API functions for searching through and manipulating the contents of the Cache, you should use them instead.