# Programmatically clear IE history, cookies, cache while IE is open

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, com

If I have an instance of IE open, with access to the underlying COM objects (IWebBrowser2 etc...) can I programmatically clear out all of the history, cookies and cached data?

Is there a way to do it in both private mode and non private mode without closing the browser and reopening it?

I have tried spawning `rundll32.exe inetcpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 1023` with various combinations of the bit flags passed as arguments, but it only seems to work when the browser is closed, and I need a solution that allows the browser to stay open.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911713/delete-internet-explorer-8-history-cookies-cache-and-passwords-with-c

Comment: This is undocumented and changes over time, but you could try tricks like installing a global CBT or callwndproc hook, then calling the  `ShowDeleteBrowsingHistoryDialog(HWND hWndParent)` function exported by `inetcpl.cpl`, catching the dialog it would display from your hook to make it invisible, then programmatically check the boxes in there and send a command message simulating the submit button, and use the global hook again to also hide the progress windows displayed by the subprocesses spawned by this function.

Comment: Note that this function must be called with medium integrity level, otherwise it would clean only low-integrity data. You could also play a bit more with `ClearMyTracksByProcess` which, since newer Windows versions (not sure which exactly) takes different kinds of arguments: `Flags:AAA WinX:BBB WinY:CCC IEFrame:DDD` (where A, B, C are decimal and D is hexadecimal and always uses 16 digits) - Flags appears to be the flags values you know already (although new ones were added), then there is progress window pos. and possibly HWND of the IEFrame window. This *might* be used to update IE about it.

Comment: However, `ClearMyTracksByProcess` must be called once with medium integrity level and once with low integrity level (normally `ShowDeleteBrowsingHistoryDialog` does this for you), and my Windows 10 also calls it a third time with flag `0x10000000` ANDed to the normal flags. Not sure what this one does, it's not documented in [this a bit older list of flags](https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest/blob/master/agent/wptdriver/wpt_settings.cc#L778)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caching is done by wininet, not mshtml.

There are good samples of this at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383928(VS.85).aspx